# Tricky Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I've been struggling to figure out a table relationship for the past two days, I'm sure that the solution is simple but it is alluding me.

Four tables/models are involved (including a pivot table):

1. `Skill` - skills table. A `Skill` belongs to a `SkillGroup` and belongs to many `Candidates` (candidate_skill pivot table)
2. `Candidate` - candidates table. Contains personal information on a candidate, not terribly related to the issue.
3. `SkillGroup` - skill_groups table. Each Skill Group has many Skills.

I want to be able to retrieve Skill objects possessed by a `Candidate` grouped by the `SkillGroup`. For example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Information Technology (Skill Group)",
    "slug": "information-technology",
    "created_at": "2016-05-07 23:58:23",
    "updated_at": "2016-05-07 23:58:23",
    "skills": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Web Development (Skill)",
        "slug": "web-development",
        "description": "Web developers primarily focus on the back-end of websites",
        "created_at": "2016-05-07 23:58:55",
        "updated_at": "2016-05-07 23:58:55",
        "skill_group_id": 1,
        "candidates": [
          {
            "first_name": "John (Candidate)",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "pivot": {
              "skill_id": 1,
              "candidate_id": 6
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is easy to accomplish with the following code, but I want to retrieve only results (`SkillGroup` -> `Skills` -> `Candidate`) for a specific candidate.

```
\App\SkillGroup::with('skills.candidates')->get();
```

I have tried the following (and everything else I can think of), the candidate_id does not seem to affect the query - I see skills that are not possessed by the given candidate.

```
\App\SkillGroup::with(['skills.candidates' => function($query) {
            $query->whereCandidateId(6);
        }])->get();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Giedrius Kiršys, I was able to come up with the following:

```
\App\SkillGroup::with(['skills.candidates' => function($query) {
            $query->wherePivot('candidate_id', 8)->addSelect('candidates.id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
        }])->whereHas('skills.candidates', function($q) {
            $q->whereCandidateId(8);
        })->get();
```

This only retrieves `SkillGroup` results with `Skill`s with a `Candidate` with the given ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to query by pivot table attribute, but You are querying by `candidates.candidate_id` attribute.

You can do it like this:

```
\App\SkillGroup::with(['skills.candidates' => function($query) {
     $query->wherePivot('candidate_id', 6);
}])->get();
```